# Memory Leak in SymMatrixBlock

Tags: c++, memory, simulation

I am trying to use a symMatrixBlock representation for the cloth simulation.
The following class stores a symmetric matrix nxn who's each element is a 3x3 matrix (represented as Mat33 class)

```
class SymMatrixBlocks
{
public:
    int size;
    int *rowstart;
    std::vector<int> col_lookup;
    std::vector<Mat33 *> matBlock;
    bool bAllZero;
public:
    SymMatrixBlocks(int size);
    SymMatrixBlocks(const SymMatrixBlocks &src);
    ~SymMatrixBlocks();

    void Zero(void);

    SymMatrixBlocks& operator=(const SymMatrixBlocks &src);
    SymMatrixBlocks& operator+=(const SymMatrixBlocks &src);
    SymMatrixBlocks& operator-=(const SymMatrixBlocks &src);
    SymMatrixBlocks& operator*=(double con);
    Mat33* getMatBlock(int row, int col);
    void SetDiag(DiagonalMatrix &src, DiagonalMatrix &ret);
    void print();
    Mat33* operator() (int row, int col);
};

inline const SymMatrixBlocks operator +(const SymMatrixBlocks &lhs, const SymMatrixBlocks &rhs)
{
    return SymMatrixBlocks(lhs) += rhs;
}

inline const SymMatrixBlocks operator -(const SymMatrixBlocks &lhs, const SymMatrixBlocks &rhs)
{
    return SymMatrixBlocks(lhs) -= rhs;
}

inline const SymMatrixBlocks operator *(const SymMatrixBlocks &lhs, double rhs)
{
    return SymMatrixBlocks(lhs) *= rhs;
}

inline const SymMatrixBlocks operator *(double lhs, const SymMatrixBlocks &rhs)
{
    return SymMatrixBlocks(rhs) *= lhs;
}
}

SymMatrixBlocks& SymMatrixBlocks::operator+=(const SymMatrixBlocks &src)
{

    if (size != src.size)
        return *this;


    if (src.bAllZero)
        return *this;

    int i, j, start, length;

    for (i = 0; i<src.size; i++)
    {
        start = src.rowstart[i];
        length = src.rowstart[i + 1] - start;
        for (j = 0; j<length; j++)
            (*((*this)(i, src.col_lookup[start + j]))) += (*(src.matBlock[start + j]));
    }

    return *this;
}

    Mat33* SymMatrixBlocks::operator() (int row, int col)
{
    int i, start, l, length;

    bAllZero = false;


    if (row > col)
    {
        start = row;
        row = col;
        col = start;
    }

    start = rowstart[row];

    length = rowstart[row + 1] - start;

    for (l = 0; l<length; l++)
        if (col_lookup[start + l] == col)
            break;

    if ((length != 0) && (l != length))
    {

        return matBlock[start + l];
    }
    else
    {

        for (l = 0; l<length; l++)
            if (col_lookup[start + l] >= col)
                break;

        col_lookup.insert(col_lookup.begin() + start + l, col);
        Mat33 *tempmat = new Mat33();
        matBlock.insert(matBlock.begin() + start + l, tempmat);

        for (i = row + 1; i <= size; i++)
            rowstart[i]++;

        return matBlock[start + l];
    }
}
```

when I run the following line it gives memory leakage. Can anyone spot it out?

*tm1 = *df_dx * h;   // all these are object of the SymMtrixBlocks class.

Comment: can you post your copy c'tor code?

Comment: `Mat33 *tempmat = new Mat33();` ? Unless insert gives ownership of that pointer to matBlock, it is never freed. I can't tell because I dont see source of Mat33